# Broadcast Receiver is not working properly

Tags: android

I am experimenting with broadcast receiver in android and I have this class as broadcast receiver:

```
public class BroadcastInbuilt extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context,"Battery Low, Please Charge!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.i("BroadcastPersonal","Happening");
        MainActivity.b1.setText("Change text if working!!");
    }
}
```

I have added this in Android Manifest inside application tag:

```
        <receiver
            android:name=".BroadcastInbuilt"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

There is no code in my main activity. When I change my battery level to low the toast does not appear. i am following the android tutorial and I have done exactly same as told here

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uf4V5OSJji8&list=PLlyCyjh2pUe9wv-hU4my-Nen_SvXIzxGB&index=44

Result is at 9:40 in video. Now his app shows toast but mine does not.

Answer (score 1):

I did some research and found out that you should not register your receiver in Android Manifest but register them dynamically through programming.

```
        BroadcastReceiver myBroadcast = new BroadcastInbuilt(); // name of class which extends BroadcastReceiver
        IntentFilter filter =new IntentFilter(BatteryManager.EXTRA_BATTERY_LOW);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW);
        this.registerReceiver(myBroadcast, filter);
```

Be sure to unregister broadcast in onDestroy()

```
unregisterReceiver(myBroadcast);
```

Note: if receiver was registered in onCreate() then it should be unregistered in onDestroy().If it was registered in onResume() then it should be unregistered in onPause().